# How can one create an iterator in SQL that counts through rows as if they are in a set?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, while-loop, sql-update, database-cursor

I have been looking into ways to do this in a single UPDATE statement but have not been successful.

This is a sample of what the dataset I am working with looks like:

```
+-------------------------+----------+--------------+----+--------+
|        TIMESTAMP        | USERNAME |    VALUE     | ID | IsDupe |
+-------------------------+----------+--------------+----+--------+
| 2020-02-12 07:00:03.000 | LINA     | ORDER1       |  1 |      0 |
| 2020-02-12 07:00:03.000 | LINA     | ITEM1        |  2 |      0 |
| 2020-02-12 07:09:09.000 | LINA     | FINISH BUILD |  3 |      0 |
| 2020-02-12 07:09:10.000 | LINA     | ORDER1       |  4 |      0 |
| 2020-02-12 07:09:11.000 | LINA     | ITEM2        |  5 |      0 |
| 2020-02-12 07:24:07.000 | LINA     | FINISH BUILD |  6 |      0 |
| 2020-02-12 07:24:08.000 | NAGA     | ORDER2       |  7 |      0 |
| 2020-02-12 07:24:10.000 | NAGA     | ITEM3        |  8 |      0 |
| 2020-02-12 07:45:06.000 | NAGA     | FINISH BUILD |  9 |      0 |
| 2020-02-12 07:45:12.000 | NAGA     | FINISH BUILD | 10 |      1 |
| 2020-02-12 07:45:13.000 | XELLOS   | ORDER3       | 11 |      0 |
| 2020-02-12 07:45:14.000 | XELLOS   | ITEM4        | 12 |      0 |
| 2020-02-12 07:56:36.000 | XELLOS   | FINISH BUILD | 13 |      0 |
| 2020-02-12 07:56:39.000 | GOURRY   | ORDER4       | 14 |      0 |
| 2020-02-12 07:56:40.000 | GOURRY   | ITEM5        | 15 |      0 |
| 2020-02-12 08:30:11.000 | GOURRY   | FINISH BUILD | 17 |      0 |
+-------------------------+----------+--------------+----+--------+
```

What I want to do is create an additional column that works as an iterator, breaking each of these rows into sets of three, like so:

```
+-------------------------+----------+--------------+-------+--------+-------+
|        TIMESTAMP        | USERNAME |    VALUE     | IDCol | IsDupe | SetID |
+-------------------------+----------+--------------+-------+--------+-------+
| 2020-02-12 07:00:03.000 | LINA     | ORDER1       |     1 |      0 | 1     |
| 2020-02-12 07:00:03.000 | LINA     | ITEM1        |     2 |      0 | 1     |
| 2020-02-12 07:09:09.000 | LINA     | FINISH BUILD |     3 |      0 | 1     |
| 2020-02-12 07:09:10.000 | LINA     | ORDER1       |     4 |      0 | 2     |
| 2020-02-12 07:09:11.000 | LINA     | ITEM2        |     5 |      0 | 2     |
| 2020-02-12 07:24:07.000 | LINA     | FINISH BUILD |     6 |      0 | 2     |
| 2020-02-12 07:24:08.000 | NAGA     | ORDER2       |     7 |      0 | 3     |
| 2020-02-12 07:24:10.000 | NAGA     | ITEM3        |     8 |      0 | 3     |
| 2020-02-12 07:45:06.000 | NAGA     | FINISH BUILD |     9 |      0 | 3     |
| 2020-02-12 07:45:12.000 | NAGA     | FINISH BUILD |    10 |      1 | NULL  |
| 2020-02-12 07:45:13.000 | XELLOS   | ORDER3       |    11 |      0 | 4     |
| 2020-02-12 07:45:14.000 | XELLOS   | ITEM4        |    12 |      0 | 4     |
| 2020-02-12 07:56:36.000 | XELLOS   | FINISH BUILD |    13 |      0 | 4     |
| 2020-02-12 07:56:39.000 | GOURRY   | ORDER4       |    14 |      0 | 5     |
| 2020-02-12 07:56:40.000 | GOURRY   | ITEM5        |    15 |      0 | 5     |
| 2020-02-12 08:30:11.000 | GOURRY   | FINISH BUILD |    17 |      0 | 5     |
+-------------------------+----------+--------------+-------+--------+-------+
```

I have tried looking up iterative statements in SQL but there have been huge concerns about performance as this is going to be a relatively large set of data and this statement would need to be run during the day, impacting production.

Also note that there are potentially duplicates or other errors contained within the dataset. Rows where IsDupe is set to 1 must be ignored from this statement.

I've been trying to build a cursor to do this, but have been running into numerous problems with syntax as well as just general inexperience writing cursors:

```
DECLARE @MyCursor CURSOR;
DECLARE @SetID INT;
DECLARE @OUTPUTNUM TINYINT;
DECLARE @COUNTER TINYINT;
BEGIN
    SET @MyCursor = CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FOR
    SELECT IsDupe from dbo.MyDataTable
        WHERE IsDupe != 1
    OPEN @MyCursor 
    FETCH NEXT FROM @MyCursor INTO @SetID

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN
      SET @COUNTER = 0;
      SET @OUTPUTNUM = 1;
      WHILE @COUNTER < 3
        BEGIN 
            UPDATE dbo.MyDataTable SET dbo.MyDataTable.SetID = @OUTPUTNUM
            SET @COUNTER = @COUNTER + 1
        END 
        SET @COUNTER = 0;
        SET @OUTPUTNUM =  @OUTPUTNUM + 1
      FETCH NEXT FROM @MyCursor 
      INTO @SetID 
    END; 

    CLOSE @MyCursor ;
    DEALLOCATE @MyCursor;
END;
```

When I run this, I get the following message:

```
[2:07:54 PM]    Started executing query at Line 1

Commands completed successfully. 

Total execution time: 00:00:00.026
```

But no results, the SetID column values are still all null.

Comment: Fortunately your cursor isn't working. A cursor is the wrong tool for the job here. The reason your code isn't working is because your update statement has no where clause so it is updating the entire table over and over and over. The biggest issue I see here is that you have no key of any kind. There is no way to know that row 1 and row 2 are part of the same group.

Comment: With the windows function you can accomplish it, you can look at my answer below

Comment: @Sean Lange Thank you for your comment. There is no key in this table unfortunately, it's just a mess of data. I've been tasked with adding some structure to this data and am trying to figure out a way to construct a makeshift set of keys based off of the pattern the data is supposed to be following: ORDER ->ITEM->FINISH BUILD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it without cursor using windows functions:

```
select [TIMESTAMP], USERNAME, VALUE, ID, IsDupe,  
case
when IsDupe = 1 then null
     else DENSE_RANK()over(order by GroupID)
end as SetID 
from(
    select 
    *, 
    case when value like 'ORDER%' then ID
         when value like 'ITEM%' then lag(ID,1)over (order by ID)  
         when value like 'FINISH BUILD%' then lag(ID,2)over (order by ID)
    end as GroupID
    from #tmp where IsDupe = 0
)a 

    union
    select 
    [TIMESTAMP], USERNAME, VALUE, ID, IsDupe, null as SetID   
    from #tmp where IsDupe = 1
order by ID
```

Here is my full example:

```
drop table #tmp

select '2020-02-12 07:00:03.000' as TIMESTAMP, 'LINA'  as USERNAME   , 'ORDER1'  as VALUE     ,  1 as ID ,      0 as IsDupe   into #tmp
union select  '2020-02-12 07:00:03.000' , 'LINA'     , 'ITEM1'        ,  2 ,      0 
union select  '2020-02-12 07:09:09.000' , 'LINA'     , 'FINISH BUILD' ,  3 ,      0 
union select  '2020-02-12 07:09:10.000' , 'LINA'     , 'ORDER1'       ,  4 ,      0 
union select  '2020-02-12 07:09:11.000' , 'LINA'     , 'ITEM2'        ,  5 ,      0 
union select  '2020-02-12 07:24:07.000' , 'LINA'     , 'FINISH BUILD' ,  6 ,      0 
union select  '2020-02-12 07:24:08.000' , 'NAGA'     , 'ORDER2'       ,  7 ,      0 
union select  '2020-02-12 07:24:10.000' , 'NAGA'     , 'ITEM3'        ,  8 ,      0 
union select  '2020-02-12 07:45:06.000' , 'NAGA'     , 'FINISH BUILD' ,  9 ,      0 
union select  '2020-02-12 07:45:12.000' , 'NAGA'     , 'FINISH BUILD' , 10 ,      1 
union select  '2020-02-12 07:45:13.000' , 'XELLOS'   , 'ORDER3'       , 11 ,      0 
union select  '2020-02-12 07:45:14.000' , 'XELLOS'   , 'ITEM4'        , 12 ,      0 
union select  '2020-02-12 07:56:36.000' , 'XELLOS'   , 'FINISH BUILD' , 13 ,      0 
union select  '2020-02-12 07:56:39.000' , 'GOURRY'   , 'ORDER4'       , 14 ,      0 
union select  '2020-02-12 07:56:40.000' , 'GOURRY'  , 'ITEM5'        , 15 ,      0 
union select  '2020-02-12 08:30:11.000' , 'GOURRY'   , 'FINISH BUILD' , 17 ,      0  
order by ID

select [TIMESTAMP], USERNAME, VALUE, ID, IsDupe,  
case
when IsDupe = 1 then null
     else DENSE_RANK()over(order by GroupID)
end as SetID 
from(
    select 
    *, 
    case when value like 'ORDER%' then ID
         when value like 'ITEM%' then lag(ID,1)over (order by ID)  
         when value like 'FINISH BUILD%' then lag(ID,2)over (order by ID)
    end as GroupID
    from #tmp where IsDupe = 0
)a 

    union
    select 
    [TIMESTAMP], USERNAME, VALUE, ID, IsDupe, null as SetID   
    from #tmp where IsDupe = 1
order by ID
```

Output:

```
        TIMESTAMP         USERNAME     VALUE      IDCol  IsDupe  SetID 
 2020-02-12 07:00:03.000  LINA      ORDER1            1       0  1     
 2020-02-12 07:00:03.000  LINA      ITEM1             2       0  1     
 2020-02-12 07:09:09.000  LINA      FINISH BUILD      3       0  1     
 2020-02-12 07:09:10.000  LINA      ORDER1            4       0  2     
 2020-02-12 07:09:11.000  LINA      ITEM2             5       0  2     
 2020-02-12 07:24:07.000  LINA      FINISH BUILD      6       0  2     
 2020-02-12 07:24:08.000  NAGA      ORDER2            7       0  3     
 2020-02-12 07:24:10.000  NAGA      ITEM3             8       0  3     
 2020-02-12 07:45:06.000  NAGA      FINISH BUILD      9       0  3     
 2020-02-12 07:45:12.000  NAGA      FINISH BUILD     10       1  NULL  
 2020-02-12 07:45:13.000  XELLOS    ORDER3           11       0  4     
 2020-02-12 07:45:14.000  XELLOS    ITEM4            12       0  4     
 2020-02-12 07:56:36.000  XELLOS    FINISH BUILD     13       0  4     
 2020-02-12 07:56:39.000  GOURRY    ORDER4           14       0  5     
 2020-02-12 07:56:40.000  GOURRY    ITEM5            15       0  5     
 2020-02-12 08:30:11.000  GOURRY    FINISH BUILD     17       0  5
```

Comment: This works great until there are two entries being added at the same time and the IDCol no longer holds sequential values for a single "group". No fault of your code, it is a big oversight in the table architecture.

Comment: @SeanLange, indeed, this code relies on the fact that IDCol is incremental and unique, you are right. :-)